# Python Error Typerror in first script (NEW request at bottom)

Tags: python

The point of the script is to tell you what day of the week it will be after 'X' amount of days from a given day.

I've been learning how to code for a few hours so bear with me.

```
    # Prompt the user for input
print("This scipt is useful in finding out what day of the week it \
will be after 'X' ammount of days in relation to the current date.")
sunday = Sunday = 0
monday = Monday = 1
tuesday = Tuesday = 2
wednesday = Wednesday = 3
thursday = Thursday = 4
friday = Friday = 5
saturday = Saturday = 6
print(" ")
todaysDate = input("Enter todays date: ")
daysFromToday = int(input("Enter a integer for days from today: "))


# Compute equasion

daysFromDate = ((todaysDate + daysFromToday) % 7)


# Display results
print(" ")
print("Today is", todaysDate, "and in", daysFromToday, "days it will be", daysFromDate)
print("  ")
print("Sunday = 0, \
Monday = 1, \
Tuesday = 2, \
Wednesday = 3, \
Thursday = 4, \
Friday = 5,   \
Saturday = 6")
input("Press enter to close: ")
```

My error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Desktop\daysfromdate.py", line 18, in <module>
    daysFromDate = ((todaysDate + daysFromToday) % 7)
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

I fixed by using

```
todaysDate = eval(input("Enter todays date: "))
```

now my script runs fine, but last question is how do I make it answer with the word version of the variables?

Current output is

```
Today is 0 and in 100 days it will be 2
```

I would like it to be

```
Today is Sunday in 100 days it will be Tuesday
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it you're using Python 3.x? If so, then

```
todaysDate = input("Enter todays date: ")
```

will return a string (`str`) object, which you should convert to an integer like you did for `daysFromToday`. I.e.,

```
todaysDate = int(input("Enter todays date: "))
```

(In older Python versions, `input` would do this conversion for you.)

**EDIT**: alright, I see what you're trying to do. Please consider *not* using `eval` for this, as `eval` is a very unsafe construct that allows a user to execute arbitrary code. A cleaner solution would be:

```
weekdays = {"sunday": 0,
            "monday": 1,
            ...
            "saturday": 6}
dayoftheweek = weekdays[input("Enter the day of the week: ")]
```

Comment: I tried that, but when you use letters at the first prompt (Sunday, sunday, monday, etc), it breaks and gives the error "line 12, in <module>
    todaysDate = int(input("Enter todays date: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'sunday'"

Comment: I fixed it by using eval(input

Comment: @user2059268: I see. I thought you'd want to input an integer. Please see the updated answer for a clean solution; calling `eval` on user input is a security hazard.

Comment: I tried to use the suggested way, and right off the bat I get a syntax error for line 4, 'weekdays = ("sunday" : 0," saying the colon is the error. Also why is eval a secuirty hazard? Thanks for your help. The updated code using your code: http://pastebin.com/JFJt5akf

Comment: @Morris That's a `{`, not a `(`. As for the security implications: suppose you do this in a webapp and a user inputs `"database_password"` in a field that you subsequently `eval`? (Google for "Python eval security" if you're not convinced.)

Comment: Okay with that I get "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File  line 13, in <module>
    todaysDate = weekdays(input("Enter todays date: "))
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: @Morris: use square brackets around the call to `input`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually runs on my version of python however your issue may be with your variable 'todaysDate', you haven't converted it to an int. Try changing:

```
todaysDate = input("Enter todays date: ")
```

To:

```
todaysDate = int(input("Enter todays date: "))
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: I changed it from "todaysDate = input("Enter todays date: ")" to "todaysDate = eval(input("Enter todays date: "))" And got it working. int wouldn't work because I would also like to use letters (ie sunday, monday)